# Best way to connect Raspberry Pi Pico to apartment monitor?

Tags: pins, poe, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to power my Raspberry Pi Pico using the existing power connection for my apartment monitor ([link to manual](https://manualzilla.com/doc/5763874/700ip-i2-user-manual---smart-bus-home-automation-control))

I note on the back of the monitor, there are unused pins, specifically a 12V and GND pin, which the manufacturer claims is for connecting an alarm/siren to the system (page 21 of manual). I want to connect my Pico here instead.

I'm just starting out with electronics, so any guidance here would be appreciated. Can I just connect jumper wires to these two pins, and find some kind of adapter to connect to the Pico's micro USB port? If you are wondering how the monitor itself is powered, there is a PoE injector which provides power directly to the monitor - I do not see a way to use these PoE injector to also power the Pico.

The reason why I want a Raspberry Pi Pico connected here is because it runs automation scripts when the monitor rings using a connected microphone (i.e. delivery person calling front door, Pico hears ring and triggers automation).

Any guidance is very much appreciated!

Comment: Cool project - but what does your landlord think about the idea ... ?

Comment: Well... I guess as there are no permanent changes it should be fine. I'm not destroying or breaking anything (hopefully), so I should just be able to unplug everything when I move out